# Dynamically returning a sitemap with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, xml, vue.js, routes, sitemap

I am working on a vue js project which has multiple tenants.  I am trying to find a solution where I can dynamically generate an xml file for each tenant.  Tenants are identified by the url, so example.com/sitemap.xml would be one sitemap, tenant 2 would be example1.com/sitemap.xml and a different sitemap.  Both of the urls hit the same server but load different data because of their domain. In turn I need to make the sitemap.xml dynamically generated as well.

I have been doing some research and I have used routes in my project but I'm not sure if I can set a route for an actual filename, and if so is it possible to return an xml response straight from vue through javascript.  I previously tried something similar for generating html outside of my application.  So I had a route call it /test, which would load a component called test, the component would then have javscript code that replaces the html document with some other html.  Would this possibly be an approach to use?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-router-middleware

I also found the package above and another similar one, that looks to do what I need by allowing me to intervene between route changes.  However, I am not sure if this will allow me to return xml, the example seems to have logic and then end with next(), wondering if instead of calling next I can actually just return the xml document at that point.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a regular Vue app, it is running on the client side not the server side. So for all routes, your webserver returns index.html. Once loaded, vue router initialises on the client and detects the route to show the appropriate view/components.

So a request to example.com/sitemap.xml returns index.html

I would guess that web crawlers are expecting the following header in the response, and the response body of an XML document for sitemaps.

```
content-type: text/xml;
```

You may be able to generate on the client side if crawlers run the javascript but I would suggest it is better to generate server side and return plain old XML. Your server side code should be able to generate this and switch based on the tenant. 
Then in the server put a special route for /sitemap.xml to not return the vue app